# how to fire a Mysql trigger on an specific date and time

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures, triggers

I have to call a store procedure at the end of each month, i just need to know how to fire  a trigger on an specific date and time to call my stored procedure.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can't do this. Instead, you should use a [cronjob](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference). If you're on a Linux system, you can create a script or program that runs your stored procedure and schedule it for execution using the `crontab` command.

In the command line, writing `crontab -e` will allow you to edit your cronjobs. In here, you can add

```
0 5 L * ? * /path/to/script.pl
```

This will run `/path/to/script.pl` at 5 AM, the last day of every month.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL triggers are responses to query events - the clock ticking is not one of them. If you need to execute something at a specific date/time, use an external job scheduler (e.g. cron) to trigger the job.

As stated in the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html):

```
MySQL triggers are activated by SQL statements only.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create an event.

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
    ON SCHEDULE
      period_of_time
    DO
      your_code_here
```